# PyCharm "mark directory as sources root" allows import from local folder but script fails to import

Tags: python-3.x, path, python-import

I have a Python 3.8  project with two files: `src/utils/adder.py` and `src/main/addition_handler.py`. I use `mark root directory as` on `src`.

`adder.py`

```
class MyAdder:
    def __init__(self, name='human', age=0):
      pass

    @staticmethod
    def add(a,b):
        return a+b
```

`addition_handler.py`

```
from utils.adder import MyAdder
print(MyAdder.add(8,2340))
```

`addition_handler.py` runs as expected in PyCharm, but fails in console.

```
from utils.adder import MyAdder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

How to fix this?